# Custom Sort Function

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a class

```
class Foo {
  private:
    unsigned int n;
    std::vector<double> label;

  public:
    //Methods for getting/setting the private variables
    std::vector<double>& getLabel(){ //This method is NOT exclusively used for sorting
      return label;
    }
}
```

I have another class that contains a vector of Foo and I would like to sort the vector based on the label.

```
bool OtherClass::sort(const Foo &a, const Foo &b){
  for unsigned int i=0; i< a.getLabel().size(); i++){
    if (a.getLabel().at(i) != b.getLabel().at(i)){
      return a.getLabel().at(i) < b.getLabel().at(i);
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

However, this fails to compile. I think it is related to the fact that I am calling getLabel() and the compiler needs me to ensure that the function is constant. If I modify the sorting function to this:

```
bool OtherClass::sort(const Foo &a, const Foo &b){
  Foo A, B;
  A=a;
  B=b;
  for unsigned int i=0; i< A.getLabel().size(); i++){
    if (A.getLabel().at(i) != B.getLabel().at(i)){
      return A.getLabel().at(i) < B.getLabel().at(i);
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

It is clearly a kludgy workaround and I would really like to understand:

1. Why the first version doesn't compile
2. Why the second version compiles
3. How can I modify the first version WITHOUT changing (i.e. adding const) the getLabel() method and have it compile

Comment: Why can you not make `getLabel` `const`? Is it not `const`? If it's not `const`, then you shouldn't be using it in a method that is declaring by contract that it will only use `const` methods. There is all kinds of hackery you can use to get around `const`, but the question is why do you want to?

Comment: Just provide a  `getLabel() const` overload.

Comment: @juanchopanza I feel like if you are overloading something to make it `const`, you're doing it wrong since either a) You could have made it `const` in the first place, or b) It's doing something different and thus isn't the same method. An exception to that would I guess be if you return a reference to a data-structure and wanted to change the constness of that (such as making two different forms of the `iterator` method, one for a `const` iterator and one for a non-`const` one), but that subset is very small.

Comment: @aruisdante It is normally fine, but it depends on the return type of the function, which we don't know. So either `const` and  non-`const` overloads, or a single `const` one.

Comment: @aruisdante: I think that is precisely the issue. getLabel() returns a reference to the "label" vector so that I could make changes to the vector from other classes. Then, the need to sort came along and so I just assumed that this would work like other custom sorting functions that I had written before. Clearly, this was not the case.

Comment: I've included a sample implementation of getLabel() in the example class above. I'd appreciate any suggestions or the proper way to address/think about this problem.

Comment: Yep, in that case @juanchopanza's suggestion is correct, simply add a `const` overload of the `getLabel` method (I.E. `const std::vector<double>& getLabel() const{`), and the compiler will automatically figure out which to use. Obviously you will have to respect the `constness` of the returned label vector, but you do that already in this case.